# Separating merge file into different file

Tags: bash, perl, sed

I have a list of files in which I have text sorted according to labels. One of the labels is `A` and the other is `A=X`.

For example like this

```
A
QMAX3427
A=X
QMAX567897
```

Now I want to make two different files one with the `A` and one with the `A=X` contents

This can be easily done with grep by `grep -w A > output.txt`.

Is there any other option?

Comment: Are there really blank lines in your data file? Are there always just two entries?

Comment: Nope ther are not blank lines and it is always the same A and A=X

Comment: If there are no blank lines, perhaps you could edit your question so that your sample data looks more (preferably exactly!) like the real thing.

Comment: If i am removing the lines Dave it is becoming worse in format :)

Comment: Please [learn how to edit your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Are you saying you want to copy the second line of all the files into one place, and the fourth lines into another place? You say that `grep -w A > output.txt` works for you, but that will just copy all the `A` and `A=X` lines to `output.txt`. What do you really want?

Comment: Thanks Borodin, sorry for the misunderstanding. I meant to say that it takes the files and outputs two separate files one with having A and its content and one having the A=X and its content.

Comment: I think you need `grep ^A$ -A1 *.txt` and `grep ^A=X$ -A1 *.txt`. Why do you want an alternative to `grep`?

Comment: Thanks Borodin but i think that will not as it when i will use for extract the A=X it will also extract the A ones also.

Comment: @user3263699: Did you try it? The regex patterns that I have shown match the *whole line*. I have also tested it.

Comment: Yes i tried it. When i am extracting the A=X it is working fine but when i am extracting the A only then A=X is also coming

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR%2{o=$0;next}{print > o}' file
```